# To enable button if all the textfields are filled in ios

Tags: ios, button, uitextfield

I have designed a signup form in ios with four `UITextField`s and a `UIButton`. I have set the buttons' `enabled` property to `NO` by default. Now I want to enable the button only when all the four textfields are filled. Can you please help me out with this as I a new to ios, and stuck with this issue.

Comment: better way is to check on button click if all four textfields are filled or not. if yes then allow your action and if not then give alert for particular textfield.

Comment: can provide code for this if you need.

Answer (score 3):

A better way would be to use the `didChange` method like the `UITextViewDelegate` method, but as we know the `UITextFieldDelegate` does not have a `didChange` method. You can manually add behaviour. You can use the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` method, but personally I would advise not to override methods unless you absolutely have to.

You can add behaviour using:

```
[myTextField1 addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];//And so on for all your text fields
```

And in the target method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField*)textField{

    if (myTextField1.text.length > 0 && myTextField2.text.length > 0 && myTextField3.text.length > 0 && myTextField4.text.length > 0){

        myButton.enabled = YES;

    } else {

        myButton.enabled = NO;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Further, if you want to make sure they are enabled *only* if the user has entered valid text, and not empty spaces, you may use the following to get the trimmed text, check if this trimmed text has length > 0:

```
NSUInteger textLength = [myString stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
```

Comment: Would this put a lot of strain on the system?

Comment: @milesper not a very taxing way.

Answer (score 1):

in your .h file

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

in your .m file

Write this in viewDidLoad

```
self.btnSignUp.enable=NO;  //button is disable by default
self.textField1.delegate=self;  // set delegate of text field
self.textField2.delegate=self;
self.textField3.delegate=self;
self.textField4.delegate=self;
```

Write this text field's delegate method

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField   
{

     if ([textField1.text length]>0 && [textField2.text length]>0 && [textField3.text length]>0 && [textField4.text length]>0)   // check if all the textfields are filled
    {
        self.btnSignUp.enabled:YES;   // enable button here
    }

}
```

Comment: An explanation of the code would be appreciated. Also, don't mix dot-notation with bracket notation.

Comment: Can you please give a suitable reason on Why should anyone not mix dot notation with bracket notation. It will be helpful for me as well as for other user too. Thanks.

Comment: Your code will look ugly and awkward, and would not be following traditional coding conventions. It will be dangerous and prone to syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is relatively old, but I wanna pitch in another idea. I've just implemented this using the UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification.

Register for the notification:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("textFieldDidChange:"), name: "UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification", object: nil)
```

Add the method for handling the notification. 
Set the enabled property of the button to true only if it's true that all of your text fields are not empty. 
This wouldn't be a great solution with 20 text fields, but for 2 - 5 it's fine.

```
 func textFieldDidChange(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.button.enabled = self.firstField.text != "" && self.secondField.text != ""
}
```

That method gets called every time a textfield's content changes, so the button responds in real time.

Comment: also they should remove the notification in`viewWillDisappear`.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in a slightly different way.
Instead of going through the muck of enabling/disabling the `UIButton`, I would let the `UIButton` be enabled all along and let it's targeted action method decide what to do.

Example:

```
//Sign Up button method
-(IBAction)btnSignUp:(UIButton *)sender
{
    //create a local array of the monitored textFields that should NOT be empty
    NSArray *arrTextFields = @[txtF1,txtF2,txtF3,txtF4];

    //helps quicken the process by using fast-enumeration as so:
    for (UITextField *txtFCurrent in arrTextFields) {
        if ([[txtFCurrent.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] isEqualToString:@""]) {
            NSLog(@"%@ found to be empty",txtFCurrent);

            //help direct the user to fill it
            //maybe after showing an alert but anyways...
            [txtFCurrent becomeFirstResponder];

            //don't proceed with the main button logic
            //since a required textField is empty
            return;
        }
    }

    //else...
    NSLog(@"All textfields are go... Proceed with the sign up request");
    //...
}
```