# UITextField setInputAccessoryView in shouldChangeCharactersInRange method

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I am trying to `setInputAccessoryView` in `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method. But it does not work. I can only get it working in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

I want the AccessoryView to show only when the user types something and not just show up when the user taps the `UITextField`

My current code in `textFieldDidBeginEditing`

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

        [textField setInputAccessoryView:tableView];
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Is there some workaround I can do?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Instead of using `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`, you can use a custom `textFieldDidChange:` method, if it suits your purpose. See my answer [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25215742/to-enable-button-if-all-the-textfields-are-filled-in-ios/25216056#25216056) to see how you can.

Comment: @n00bProgrammer textFieldDidChange: method still doesn't show the AccessoryView. It does enter the if statement when user types but the AccessoryView does not show...

Answer (score 0):

You can add target to your textfield as below

```
[your_textField addTarget:tableView action:@selector(textFieldValueChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

Here `textFieldValueChanged:` is custom method where you will implement your further code for table view

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run a test with a `UITableView` but I did attempt to set a `UIToolbar` as an input accessory view in `textfield:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` and it was successful. You're going to need a flag that keeps track of whether the accessory view is displayed or not so you don't run the set up code more than once. The existence of an input accessory view is only checked when the keyboard is about to be presented so you have to do a dance where you resign and then become the first responder. Also, in order for the input accessory view to display immediately after the first keyboard tap, you have to redisplay the textfield.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField
shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range
replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

    if (!self.accessoryViewDisplayed) {
        self.accessoryViewDisplayed = YES;

        UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
        toolbar.translucent = NO;
        toolbar.barTintColor = [UIColor greenColor];

        textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [textField becomeFirstResponder];
        [textField setNeedsDisplay];
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Update

After thinking about it further, you could configure your input accessory view in `viewDidLoad` and set `hidden` to `YES`. Then in the text field delegate method, you can simply set the flag and unhide the input accessory view without having to do the resign/become first responder dance.